# Pattern of HASH characters (#) with Java loop

Tags: design-patterns

Hello i need a program that reads a number and then prints a square pattern of (#) hash. But each edge needs the same number of hashes

eg

enter a number: 5

```
#####
#####
#####
#####
#####
```

this is what i have so far

```
import console;

print("write a number: ");
int n = readInt();
int nva=0;
String i="#";

while (nva<n){
   print(i);
   nva=nva + 1;

   }
 println();
```

Comment: Is this a trick question? The code you've got looks right though I don't think C++ has String if that's the language you're writing in...

Comment: That doesn't look like Java to me either, but hey, it seems he's running that code on _something_ :).

Answer (score 4):

since it is definitely HW i will give direction. Since you have to fill 2D shape you should use nested cycles - one for rows, another for columns. Is it better now?

**Edit**: You should read manual about loops. `for` is more suitable here than `while`

Comment: I was about to post almost exactly the same thing. +1 :)

Comment: Nested loops would make this slower than it has to be.  Better to just have two loops...one to create the string of n #'s (if even necessary; some languages have the built in ability to do this!), and one to output the string n times.

Comment: but how can i use for, if i am not sure how many time the hash will be printed?

Comment: `for (nva=0; nva<n; ++nva) { do stuff }`.  It works the exact same way you'd use a while loop, except that all the stuff that changes and checks your counter is in the same place (so it's easier to see when/if the loop will ever end, among other reasons).

Answer (score 1):

... or you could iterate up to n^2 and output a line break after each sequence of n chars.

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration of the loop you are printing the `#` just once.

You'll have to use another loop inside your main loop that prints `#` `n` times for each iteration of the outer loop.